# Why would tlbimp convert interfaces to coclasses?

Tags: c#, .net, com, tlbimp, coclass

It's in fact a feature that in most cases [tlbimp will convert an interface to a coclass](http://jpassing.com/2009/01/05/working-around-tlbimps-cleverness/). Specifically if in IDL I have

```
interface IFirst {
}
interface ISecond {
    HRESULT GetFirst( IFirst** );
}

coclass First {
   interface IFirst;
}
```

then tlbimp will see that `First` is the only class to implement `IFirst`, so it creates a .NET interface where `interface IFirst` is replaced with `class First`

```
interface ISecond {
    First GetFirst(); // co-class returned, not interface
}
```

which is presumably helpful in some way.

How could this be useful? I mean `class First` will have the same methods as `interface IFirst` anyway, so it doesn't add anything, so without that conversion I could just pass `interface IFirst` everywhere and get exactly the same effect. What's the use of this conversion?

Comment: +1 for the link explaining what is going on.  Thanks